# Get taxonomy parent using child slug (from merged taxonomies)

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, tax-query

So, I tried a bunch of ways to do this, but none worked.

I have an array, that has a lot of values from different taxonomies (from the same custom post type), I'm giving an example with only 2, but it can have 4, or 5, or 10.

```
Ex.: 
Types 1
    - Item a
    - Item b
    - Item c
Types 2
    - Item d
    - Item e
    - Item f
```

Those 'Item' values populate a `<select>`.

I need a way, to get the parent of the selected child. But the only info I will have is the slug and the name of the child. I will use that later for a `tax_query`.

I need to get if it's from Types 1, Types 2, etc.

**What is the code I have now:**

```
foreach ($tax_categorias as $tax_categoria) {
echo '<option value='. $tax_categoria->slug.'' . $selected . '>' . $tax_categoria->name . '</option>';

$ads_filt_categorias = $_GET['ads_filt_categorias'];
$parent_term = get_term_by('slug', $ads_filt_categorias);
```

I already tried other option, like use the slug to get the ID and then try to get the parent.

I tried `get_terms()`, `get_ancestors()`, etc

I'm probably missing something pretty basic... Any ideas what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since in most cases I would need to now the 'taxonomy', one work around I found (actually, pointe by @Howdy_McGee) was to pass the slug of the term and it's parent to the value, and then split-string.

**Here is my final code:**

```
foreach ($tax_categorias as $tax_categoria) {
    echo '<option value='. $tax_categoria->slug .'.'. $tax_categoria->taxonomy .'' . $selected . '>' . $tax_categoria->name . '</option>';
}
$ads_cat = $_GET['ads_filt_categorias'];
$list($ads_filt_categorias,$ads_categorias) = explode('.', $ads_cat);
```